# Displaying BLOB image with other content

Tags: php, mysql, html, header, blob

Firstly this is for a simple university project, so time is more important than performance of database etc.

I have a database with images stored in blob files. Now some form outputs data from this database, but i want it to also output the image, along with the text.

I realise there is a bit of code to change headers to image, but then the text wont display, so is there a way to display the image and the text on the same page?

thanks a lot,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to embed images inside HTML, but you usually do it only if you have a really good reason to. Assuming you do, you write the following code, provided that `$BLOB` is the binary raw data of the image:

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($BLOB); ?>"/>`

Comment: You can read more about [Data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use image tags like normal wherever you need the images to be, and in the src attribute, specify a PHP script along with a get argument (for instance, <img src='image.php?name=something.jpg'>). This script then authenticates the request, accesses the database, sends the appropriate headers, followed by the actual BLOB data.

Comment: This is the most common method of implementation.